# How large is the fusion plasma dielectric constant? Why does this mean radial current cannot exist in a tokamak?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, plasma-physics, dielectric

I am reading [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0029-5515/36/1/I04/meta) by Rosenbluth and Hinton (1996). In the second paragraph of the introduction, they say two things I don't understand:

1. The first, is that they claim that the "plasma dielectric constant is typically very large". Do you know a good source for what the [dielectric constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_permittivity#Lossy_medium), $\epsilon_r$, in fusion plasma typically is? I didn't know it is large, I thought it was okay to approximate the dielectric constant as $\epsilon_r\approx1$.
2. The second, is that they state that the large dielectric constant means that the net radial current can't be very large? Do you know why this is? I think the following bit of maths might explain why this is.
   From [Gauss's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law#Differential_form) we know that
   $$\mathbf{\nabla\cdot E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0\epsilon_r}.$$
   From the [Ampère–Maxwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law#Extending_the_original_law:_the_Amp%C3%A8re%E2%80%93Maxwell_equation) equation we know that
   $$\mathbf{\nabla\times B}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}+\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}.$$
   Taking the divergence and substituting for $\mathbf{\nabla\cdot E}$ gives
   $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_r}\right)+\mathbf{\nabla\cdot J}=0.$$
   Hence if $\epsilon_r\rightarrow \infty$ then $\mathbf{\nabla\cdot J}\rightarrow0$. Let $r$ denote the coordinate along the minor radius of the tokamak. If we assume poloidal and toroidal invariance then
   $$\mathbf{\nabla \cdot J} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(rJ_r\right)=0,$$
   $$\implies rJ_r = C.$$
   where $C$ is an integration constant. Since $J_r$ is finite at $r=0$, we know that $C=0$ and hence $J_r=0$.
   Is this maths correct?

Answer (score 0):

1. On page 55 of [Chen (1984)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-319-22309-4.pdf) he shows that
   $$\epsilon_R=1+\frac{\mu_0\rho c^2}{B^2},$$
   which for $n=10^{16}\mathrm{\,m}^{-3}$ and $B=0.1\mathrm{\,T}$ we have (for
   hydrogen)
   $$\frac{\mu_0\rho c^2}{B^2}=\frac{(4\pi\times10^{-7})(10^{16}) 
   (1.67\times10^{-27})(9\times10^{16})}{(0.1)^2}=189.$$
2. If the maths is correct then the questions have now been answered.